# Testing the result of Sidekiq background job with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, sidekiq

I have a model method that sends info to a sidekiq background job.  The background job changes some attributes on an object.  I want to test to make sure this is happening as expected.

The Rspec test I wrote creates the object, then runs the method and expects the attribute to be changed.  However, the attribute isn't changing and I suspect that the background job isn't running in the Rspec test.  Anyone know how to make sidekiq process a job in the test so that it actually changes the attributes

Answer (score 4):

Use the inline support in your test:

```
Sidekiq::Testing.inline! do
  model.do_something
end
```

Read more: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing